# pass asp.net literal object to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, literals

I have several asp.net literals on a page, like this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litEmailInvestigatingHealthOfficer" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

And when their corresponding textboxes are filled out from another page, it iterates through a javascript function and calls a js function: validateEmail(idNo,theliteralobject);

I've already written an ajax call to a web method and in that web method I'm wanting to make a call to an already existing asp.net function that expects an employee object and a literal object.

```
        function validateEmail(idNo, literalCtl) {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "RespPerson.aspx/validateEmails",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{empID: " + idNo + ",literal:" + literalCtl + "}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Im done');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Is it possible to pass the asp.net literal object to Javascript then to a web method? If I try to specify just the object it puts System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal in the js call and says its undefined.

Comment: It's not clear what you really mean by "pass a literal object to JavaScript."  An ASP.NET `Literal` control doesn't render any output to the page by itself, it only renders its contents (as a literal string).  You can reference the contents if they have some means of being referenced (such as being wrapped in an identifiable `div` for example), but the `Literal` itself has no client-side meaning so there's nothing JavaScript can do with it.

Comment: I was thinking more about how you could pass a literal object in asp.net codebehind to achieve different goals and I was wondering if it was possible to pass the object through js.

Comment: I'm afraid not simply because there is no client-side representation of a `Literal`.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  There's likely a much simpler approach.

Comment: I was just hoping I could reuse the existing asp.net method that was already written. But if its not possible, then I'll just use the web method to do my validation, I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Literal does not represent any html tags. what it renders in html is what you put in it's Text property.

```
litEmailInvestigatingHealthOfficer.Text = "some text";

<div>
<asp:Literal ID="litEmailInvestigatingHealthOfficer" runat="server" />
</div>

html output:
<div>
some text
</div>
```

while

```
lblEmailInvestigatingHealthOfficer.Text = "some text";

<div>
<asp:Label ID="lblEmailInvestigatingHealthOfficer" runat="server" />
</div>

html output:
<div>
<span id='lblEmailInvestigatingHealthOfficer'>some text</span>
</div>
```